# Every Video in Fast forward motion 14.04

Tags: video, 14.04, pulseaudio

No Sound just fast playing video it doesn't matter which ever player or browser i use.
While checking in System Monitor **pulseaudio** in very high priority.
I tried to uninstall and re-install pulse audio but nothing changes..
Stopped all the plugins in browser nothing happended.

> one Observation was that while playing video in youtube when i ended the pulseaudio process using system monitor the video became normal but no audio....

Answer (score 2):

I get this issue when selecting an alternative sound output. If I have the analogue output selected all is fine. Do you have more than 1 output option in sound settings? If you do try changing it.

[image]